# How to verify is Wsus itself is correctly patched?

Tags: wsus, windows-update

Wsus 4.0 on Windows 2012 R2 server.

Help-> Abit Update services says Version: **6.3.9600.18694**

In the main page version is **6.3.9600.18838**

Cannot find any official info to determine if Wsus is completely update.

Besides I have no evidence that patch KB3159706 is installed.I don't remember to the post install phase and systeminfo doesn't list it. How can I know if it is effectively installed and post install has been executed ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, wsus server is never part of "approval for install" group. it is in a separated GPO group to receive all patches directly from Microsoft update center.

If you have Monthly quality rollup installed, the previous fixes maybe are included in the roll up package already. (Check for details on Roll up package) sever will only show you KB numbers for roll up you installed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if KB3159706 is included in the regular monthly Windows updates, so unless your machine is several months out of date, it should be present.

However, if you are uncertain, the definitive test is to look in the [Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/3159706/update-enables-esd-decryption-provision-in-wsus-in-windows-server-2012) for the update in question, where it says "File Information" and compare the dates and/or version numbers to the corresponding files on your server.

If any of the files on your server have a lower version number or an earlier date than that shown in the KB article, the update might not be installed.  (Note that the date shown on the server files may vary slightly depending on what time zone you are in.)